# Flutter how to set a column that wrap gridview height

Tags: flutter, gridview

i trying to make the height of column into dynamically because the more product i have i need more height for the column, down there was my code

```
Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 1000,
          child: GridView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: productsList.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 22 / 30,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 3),
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
              return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                value: productsList[i],
                child: FeedsProduct(),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

how can i set the container height dynamically?

Comment: Just Column wrap with Expanded Widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property inside GridView called : **shrinkWrap**, see [shrinkWrap property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html)

Here you can find simple example

```
class SimpleExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const SimpleExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            GridView.builder(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 30,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 22 / 30,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 3),
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Item $i"),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: by the way if i put itemcount 30 did it max it my item only for 30 even in database got 40?

Comment: I added 30 item count just to show you an example. you have to change the item count with your list.length

Comment: ah forgot about it okok

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code works exactly but you can wrap the Expanded() widget on GridView() instead of a container:

```
 Expanded(
     child: GridView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: productsList.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 22 / 30,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
            crossAxisSpacing: 3),
           itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
           return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: productsList[i],
            child: FeedsProduct(),
          );
        },
      ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

the `mainAxisExtent`affects the tile heigh.

my code:

```
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: items,
            childAspectRatio: 22/30,
            crossAxisSpacing: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 5,
            mainAxisExtent: 176,
          )
```

from the silver_grid.dart:

```
 /// The extent of each tile in the main axis. If provided it would define the
  /// logical pixels taken by each tile in the main-axis.
  ///
  /// If null, [childAspectRatio] is used instead.
  final double? mainAxisExtent;
```